# linked list in c/c++

Tags: c++

I am going to multiply two polynomial that user must enter.

in the first step (getting info from user) I got this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00a315cb in linked polinomials.exe:
  0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

I got this error after that I want to enter an other element of polynomial.

```
struct polynomial{

    float coef ;
    int exp ;
    polynomial *next ;
} *first, *second ,*result;
```

```
first = new(polynomial);
   //init first
first ->coef = 0;
first->exp = 0 ;
first->next = 0;
```

```
while(ch != 'n')
{
    cin >> temp_c ;
    cin >> temp_e ;
    first->coef = temp_c;
    first->exp = temp_e;
    cout << "Do you want to enter another ? (y or n) :" << endl;
    ch = getch();
    first = first->next;
}
```

Comment: As this is C++ rather than C, why not use a std::list?

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++. Don’t use pointers in C++, least of all in the way you do.

Comment: When you get a crash in your program, the first thing you should do is to run it in a debugger. It will help you locate the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what the cause might have been.

Comment: i did but i didn't knew why i got that crash

Comment: The logic of your loop is the wrong way around... Use `do-while` loop instead, and create all the nodes inside the loop, including the first one. Or since you are using C++, why not use a standard container such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), or [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) if you really want to use lists.

Comment: If you did, you would see that `first` is `NULL`, then you should add a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop and step through while examining `first` to see when it gets set to `NULL`.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg : it is part of a homework that i must let is pass till end of this weak. i can not use them . all of what you said is correct and thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first iteration:

```
first = first->next;
```

you assign `first` to `NULL`, because that's what `first->next` is initially. You need to allocate space for it before the assignment.

```
first->next = new polynomial;
first = first->next;
```

Also, are you sure you want to lose the pointer to the first node?

Comment: @hadirasuli use an auxiliary node instead, not `first`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate memory for the whole list.
You need to write something like this:
`first->next = new polynomial();

first = first->next;`

Otherwise, you're trying to read memory at `NULL` address.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should do:

```
second = new(polynomial);
first->next=second;
first=second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first = first->next;
```

Before this operation you must allocate a memory for a new link such as

```
first->next = new polynomial();
```

and only after that you can write

```
first = first->next;
```